# How do I render different data types from a fetched json?

Tags: react-native

I was using...

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.dataSource}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.username} {item.name}</Text>}
  keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
/>
```

...to render two texts in React Native but now I've got an uri in my json...

How do I render the image in an IM style (thumbnail, username and name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a renderItem method and then put everything you need in there. Once you make the renderItem method you can throw it into your FlatList.

```
renderItem({ item }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image
        source={{uri: item.uri}}
      />
     <Text>
       {item.username}
     </Text>
     <Text>
       {item.name}
     </Text>
</View>

 );
}
```

Then use the method inside the FlatList (the .bind makes sure it stays in the right context)

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.dataSource}
  renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
  keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
/>
```

Comment: it renders name and username only... where should I refer to the image name (in my json) here?!

Comment: I tried referencing in source={{uri: item.uri.image}} but "image" does not even show in the elements list for "uri"

Comment: Whatever your image name is inside your json structure. Do you have a object name uri? Cause thats what you're referencing when you say `item.uri.image`

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct to close the question, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You can build a component that takes your fields as its props, containing multiple `Text`s and an `Image` using your uri as the source. Style this like you would any other component, and then pass that component into `renderItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the component immediately to the `renderItem` like this if the flatlist item is not complicated ( has a lot of component )

```
<FlatList
   data={this.state.dataSource}
   renderItem={({item}) => {
         <View>
              <Image source={{uri: item.uri.image}}/>
              <Text>{item.userName}</Text>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
         </View>
   }}
   keyExtractor={(i) => i.toString()}
/>
```

Comment: Ouch, sorry. I forgot about the `uri`. 
       ```<Image source={{uri: item.uri.image}}/>```

The image uri is depends on your json data, `item.uri.image` is just an example from my code.

Comment: it does'nt work even with my "imageName" json :( actually it does not render anything... name or userName :((

Comment: this is my json by the way... {
 "name" : "",
 "items" : [],
 "names" : [{
  "imageName" : "http://blogspay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/istock-526142422.jpg",
  "name" : "Jennifer Aniston",
  "username" : "anistonj",
  "id" : 1}, {
  "imageName" : "https://www.doctorulzilei.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/stretching-3.jpg",
  "name" : "Jennifer Garner",
  "username" : "garnerj",
  "id" : 2}, {
  "imageName" : "https://www.sss.gov/portals/0/Images/Women-and-the-Draft.jpg",
  "name" : "Jennifer Lawrence",
  "username" : "lawrencej",
  "id" : 3}]}

Comment: Can i see at how you render your flatList component? You can copy your code to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com). And please give me the link of your pastebin.